# Detect server version using @elastic/elasticsearch js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Using the REST API it is possible to determine the server version number (in this case "7.10.2")

```
curl 'https://search-elasticsearch-aws-710-public-v7fycso36gekt3vjabelkne2fa.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com'
{
  "name" : "3af17e13e3e29b64cd0f32c57edadc0e",
  "cluster_name" : "206020203570:elasticsearch-aws-710-public",
  "cluster_uuid" : "i19BVkuJTjmivIeg0VRWwA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2021-07-20T13:48:00.963660Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Is it possible to return the same information using only the `@elastic/elasticsearch` js library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_info

```
const elasticsearch = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new elasticsearch.Client(options);
client.info().then(info => {
    console.log(info);
});
```

```
{
    "name": "65efdbcd59450304fa4d07a7faf0cd83",
    "cluster_name": "891817851964:content-api-es7-test",
    "cluster_uuid": "5soRYzoSQPiinSp4kDIG8B",
    "version": {
        "number": "7.10.2",
        "build_flavor": "oss",
        "build_type": "tar",
        "build_hash": "unknown",
        "build_date": "2021-07-20T13:48:00.963660Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "8.7.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```